# Metric of a rotating Cosmic String

Tags: general-relativity, field-theory, resource-recommendations, vortex, cosmic-string

I searched on the internet superficially but I couldn't find it.

Is there any reference that find the solution to Einstein's Field Equations for a **rotating** Cosmic String?

Personally haven't got the time to do the computation for the rotating flux tube extension of a 2d vortex solution to the Higgsed-$U(1)$ Yang Mills, but that's where I would definitely start from.

Comment: A rotating string of what shape? Straight? Circular? Which axis is it rotating around?

Comment: I'd say since I am interested in the local behavior, you can take the infinitly long straight line for granted. @Ghoster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Catalogue of Spacetimes" review of exact solutions to Einstein's equation, [Mueller & Graves (2009)](https://arxiv.org/abs/0904.4184), is the first place I would look.  And sure enough section 2.22 might be what you are looking for.  They pulled that metric from [Perlick (2004)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.12942/lrr-2004-9#Sec5.10), an LRR on gravitational lensing, which can point you further down the reference rabbit hole.

Comment: Many thanks. I can guess that $a$ is the inverse of the angular speed, but cannot say what $\kappa$ stands for immediately...?